# uuid_it : Can't mass-assign protected attributes: uuid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, uuid

I used [uuid_id](https://github.com/aduffeck/uuid_it) gem to generate UUID for various models in my application(Rails 3.2.5 with Ruby 1.9.3p194). I correctly followed the steps given [here](https://github.com/aduffeck/uuid_it)

I am getting this error while creating the model tagged as `uuid_it`. It works fine if I remove `uuid_it` call from the model

Here is snapshot of the log

```
SQL (2.1ms)  INSERT INTO "applications" ("created_at", "description", "name",  "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Mon, 03 Sep 2012 10:17:59 UTC +00:00], ["description", "data mining"], ["name", "BlueBerry"], ["updated_at", Mon, 03 Sep 2012 10:17:59 UTC +00:00]]
  Uuid Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "uuids".* FROM "uuids" WHERE "uuids"."uuidable_id" = 5 AND "uuids"."uuidable_type" = 'Application' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 81ms

ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: uuid):
  app/controllers/applications_controller.rb:13:in `create'
```

where line 13 is `application.create`

**EDIT**

**app/controllers/applications.rb**

```
class ApplicationsController < ApplicationController
  # some code here
  def create
    @application = Application.new(params[:application])
    @application.creator = current_user
    @application.organization = current_organization
    if @application.save
      redirect_to @application, notice: "Successfully created application."
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end
  # few lines here
end
```

Comment: add attr_accessible :uuid_it in model and check

Comment: @Amar, That also was not able to fix the problem. I had also tried `attr_accessible :uuid` in the model but it didn't work either.

Comment: Can you provide your application1.create statement? Also if you are using create statement, you can try with :without_protection => true

Comment: @Gogu edited the question to include `create` call

Comment: Looks like your model has dependency on uuid model which is failing. You need to add attr_accessible :uuid to the uuid model I guess. I cannot predict anything more based on the limited information provided.

Comment: @Gogu, As per the [Usage](https://github.com/aduffeck/uuid_it#usage) I don't have to configure anything in uuid model. Surprisingly there is no model exists for uuid